# XML query returns only first element

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to return the 3 scancode items elements within this XML, instead it returns the first element 3 times. I haven't done much with LINQ XML. I've looked through the other post on the site and there all a little different.

```
### Expected Output ###
10/14/2015
05:00
044000031910
044000031912
044000031913

10/15/2015
06:00
044000031920
044000031922
044000031923

### Current Output ###
10/14/2015
05:00
044000031910
044000031910
044000031910

10/15/2015
06:00
044000031920
044000031920
044000031920
```

XML Example

```
<Orders>
<Transaction>
    <TransDate>10/14/2015</TransDate>
    <TransTime>05:00</TransTime>
    <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <ScanCode>044000031910</ScanCode>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <ScanCode>858310004011</ScanCode>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <ScanCode>092657011712</ScanCode>
    </Item>
</Transaction>

<Transaction>
    <TransDate>10/15/2015</TransDate>
    <TransTime>06:00</TransTime>
    <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <ScanCode>044000031920</ScanCode>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber> 
        <ScanCode>858310004021</ScanCode>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <ScanCode>092657011722</ScanCode>
    </Item>
</Transaction>
```

C# Example

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
        var data = from item in doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                   select new
                   {
                       TransDate = (string)item.Element("TransDate"),
                       TransTime = (string)item.Element("TransTime"),
                       items = from order in item.Elements("Item")
                               select new
                               {
                                   ScanCode = (string)item.Element("Item").Element("ScanCode")
                               }

                   };
        foreach (var Item in data)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(Item.TransDate + Environment.NewLine);
            textBox1.AppendText(Item.TransTime + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (var item in Item.items)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(item.ScanCode + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the expected output:-

```
 select new
     {
         ScanCode = (string)order.Element("ScanCode")
     }
```

You already have `order` reference variable which holds the `Item` collection. No need to go further up, you can use `order` itself.

As per your current code you are trying to find Element `item` in `Transaction` collection so it is finding just the first one.

Comment: Worked Perfect! Thanks so much!